# When using install_ssl of the cPanel UAPI, I am experiencing "The certificate text was not valid."

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I am using the cPanel UAPI to call the install_ssl function.  I have followed the tutorial [here][1]: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Tutorial+-+Call+UAPI%27s+SSL%3A%3Ainstall_ssl+Function+in+Custom+Code#4ba262da2a5b4308828c17a2156d5dc9

However, I am getting a parse error when it is attempting to read the certificate.  I have copied the certificate from my cPanel SSL Manage UI and placed it in a file.  I know that this file is being read correctly.  However, I get the following error when it is sent via the API.

"The system could not parse the certificate because of an error: The certificate text was not valid."

I have tried url encoding the certificate and key, which did nothing.  Here is the code I used. (I am doing this in Drupal, hence the use of dpm)

function _bh_site_configure_multi_add_ssl($fulldomain) {

```
// Declare your username and password for authentication.


$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";

// Define the API call.
$cpanel_host = "myserver";
$request_uri = "https://$cpanel_host:2083/execute/SSL/install_ssl";

// Define the SSL certificate and key files.
$cert_file = realpath("/path/to/file/cert.crt");
$key_file = realpath("/path/to/file/key.key");

// Set up the payload to send to the server.
$payload = array(
    'domain' => $fulldomain,
    'cert'   => file_get_contents($cert_file),
    'key'    => file_get_contents($key_file)
);

// Set up the cURL request object.
$ch = curl_init( $request_uri );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

// Set up a POST request with the payload.
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// Make the call, and then terminate the cURL caller object.
$curl_response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

// Decode and validate output.
$response = json_decode( $curl_response );
if( empty( $response ) ) {
    dpm("The cURL call did not return valid JSON:\n");
} elseif ( !$response->status ) {
    dpm("The cURL call returned valid JSON, but reported errors:\n");
    dpm($response->errors[0] . "\n") ;
} 

dpm ($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my particular cert needed to have the cabundle.  When I went back to the installation instructions for my cert that I got from the Certificate Authority, it included a cabundle.  After I included that, it worked.